# Число не записывается в БД при запросе через PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, preparedstatement

Мне необходимо занести число в ячейку.

Вот только почему-то информация не заносится в БД.

Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

```java
private void SignUpDuuNasPDOALL(Date date, String str, Integer num) {
    String insert = "UPDATE " + ConstDUUPDO.PDO_TABLE_NAS_HARD + " SET " + str + "=?" + " WHERE DATE(" + ConstDUUPDO.DATEPDO_NH + ") = '"+ date +"'";
    try {
        PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert);
        prSt.setInt(1, ConstHrono.ADZ_DUU2M_HARD);
        prSt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Занесено в " + num + " ячейку");
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Во-первых, у вас UPDATE не ограниченный, вы во все строки в колонку str таблицы записываете одно и то же значение. Если у вас в таблице что-то есть, то ваш запрос испортит данные в колонке str во все таблице. Как правило, у UPDATE должен быть WHERE (кроме случаев, когда вам действительно нужно обновить значение во всех строках). Во-вторых, UPDATE предполагает, что есть строки, которые можно обновить. Если таких строк нет, то никакая информация и не "занесется в БД". Предполагаю, что вам нужен INSERT вместо UPDATE.

Comment: В collumn mysql это ячейка имеет переменную  int. При выполнении кода ошибок нет, но и данные не заносятся. Может вместе UPDATE  INSERT использовать? У меня конкретно в этом вопрос, к запросу и дальнейшему внесению в БД. Правильный он или нет.

Comment: @Максим UPDATE обновляет значение в существующей строке таблицы (когда данные вы уже добавили, и их нужно изменить). Если таблица пустая, то ничего не обновится. INSERT - добавляет данные в таблицу. Используйте то, что подходит для вашего случая.

Comment: @insolor , спасибо, но в INSERT, насколько я знаю, нельзя использовать WHERE, а это крайне необходимо в данном случае.

Comment: Так вы в приведенном коде и в UPDATE не используете WHERE. В INSERT и не нужно WHERE, потому что он добавляет новую строку, а WHERE накладывает ограничение на существующие строки. Вообще, опишите конкретно, что вы хотите сделать, чтобы не нужно было угадывать.

Comment: @insolor Мне необходимо по строке уже известной даты date найти колонку str и внести в нее константу ConstHrono.ADZ_DUU2M_HARD.

Comment: 1 - строка в таблице с этой датой действительно существует? 2 - покажите содержимое переменной insert. 3 - при выполнении этой строки просто через SQL необходимые действия выполняются?

Comment: 1 - да. 2- UPDATE hard_sensors_pdo_nas SET duu2m0104_zagr1=? WHERE DATE(date) = '2023-05-14' . 3 - не совсем понял вопрос( не имею такой большой опыт)

Comment: 3 - открываете консоль SQL (смотря что там у вас за база), и в ней выполняете запрос.

Comment: @insolor,  спасибо за внимание к моему вопросу. Я решил проблему. Код был правильным, а переменные передаваемые в него не совсем( благодарю за понимание моего невысокого уровня!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что формально синтаксис SQL запроса не нарушен, но условие `WHERE` выполняться не будет из-за неправильного ожидания, что переменная `Date date` будет автоматически представлена в ISO формате `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Такой формат используется по умолчанию для класса [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--):

> `public String toString()`
> Formats a date in the date escape format yyyy-mm-dd.

в отличие от класса [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--):

> `public String toString()`
> Converts this Date object to a `String` of the form:
> `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`

---

Вероятно, вам следовало использовать другой параметр в `PreparedStatement` для установки даты вместо кодирования строки при помощи метода [`PreparedStatement::setDate(int pIx, java.sql.Date date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-).

Кроме того, параметр `num` нигде НЕ используется при формировании запроса на обновление, а только при выводе сообщения.

Также при работе с `PreparedStatement` следует использовать `try-with-resources`, чтобы гарантировать его закрытие.

```java
import java.sql.Date;

private void SignUpDuuNasPDOALL(Date date, String str, Integer num) {
    String insert = String.format("UPDATE %s SET %s = ? WHERE DATE(%s) = ?",
        ConstDUUPDO.PDO_TABLE_NAS_HARD, str, ConstDUUPDO.DATEPDO_NH
    );
    try (PreparedStatement prSt = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(insert)) {
        prSt.setInt(1, ConstHrono.ADZ_DUU2M_HARD); // не num!
        prSt.setDate(2, date);
        int rowsUpdated = prSt.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Для ячейки " + num + " обновлено строк: " + rowsUpdated);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Nowhere Man,  cпасибо , но эту проблему с датой я решил до того. Спасибо за внимание к вопросу!